# Laravel wheredoesnt isn't working

Tags: php, laravel

I want to select all materials that are available in dates and hours, using foreign keys like category, subcategory and locals, other thing it's that i have to get the materials that doesn't have relationship /pivot

This is my QUERY:

```
$material = Material::with(['orders_material','locals'])
     ->whereDoesntHave('orders_material',function ($query) use ($userOrder) {
        $query->where('Material_id', null); 
     })

    ->where('Categoria_id', $idcategory)
    ->where('SubCategoria_id', $idsubcategory)
    ->where('requisitado', '0')
    ->where('estado', '1')
    ->paginate(4);
```

I have pivot relationship where, i don't have that in json data in results i need.

How to fix this?

Comment: what is your expectation??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where('x', null)` produces `where x = null`, which is a common mistake.

Always compare `null` with `is` as `where x is null`.

The eloquent way is:

```
->whereDoesntHave('orders_material',function ($query) use ($userOrder) {
    $query->whereNull('Material_id'); 
 })
```

Comment: This is not what i want, it's giving me the same result.

Comment: try dump the generated query: `\DB::enableQueryLog(); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing sub queries, you should declare relationships in Models and then call model functions as needed. That way eloquent will give you result with correct pivot relationships mentioned in models.

Comment: public function orders_material()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Orders', 'Orders_has_Material', 'Material_id', 'Orders_id')->withPivot('quantity');
     }